# Evaluation of $\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{x}\left(\ln (1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}-1\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits

$\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{x}\left(\ln (1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}-1\right)$

Here is the solution, but I don't understand it at all. Can someone please help and explain the steps needed to solve this limit?

[image: Solution]

It's not in English, but I think everyone will be able to understand.

Comment: It basically put everything in the form of $e^{f(x)}$ and evaluated the limit of $f(x)$ as $x\to 0$ by L'Hopital

Comment: Thanks for the response, im just not sure how he gets -1 in the fists row of the solution, can you explain that please?

Comment: Which step are you having a problem?

Comment: I thing he took log both sides

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it using laws of logarithm and series expansion:

$\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{x}\left(\ln (1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}-\ln(e^{x/x}))))\right)$   , as $\ln(e)=1$ , $\ln(e^{x/x})=1$

$\ln(a)-ln(b)=ln(a/b)$

$
\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{x}\left(\ln ((1+x)/e^x)^{\frac{1}{x}}\right)
$

$\ln(a^{m})=mln(a)$

$\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{x^{2}}\left(\ln ((1+x)/e^x)\right)$

$
\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{x^{2}}\left(\ln ((1+x))-ln(e^x))\right)$

$\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{x^{2}}\left((x-x^2/2 +x^3/3-x^4/4+....)-x\right)$

$\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{x^{2}}\left((-x^2/2 +x^3/3-...\right)$

Cancelling $x^{2}$ from denominator and numerator

$\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \left((-1/2 +x/3-x^{2}/4+...\right)$

Apply the limit and the value comes out to be -1/2

Answer (score 0):

Considering $$A= \frac{1}{x}\left(\log (1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}-1\right)$$ compose Taylor series
$$\log (1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}={\frac{1}{x}}\log (1+x)={\frac{1}{x}}\left(x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+O\left(x^4\right) \right)=1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}+O\left(x^3\right)$$ So $$A=\frac{1}{x}\left(-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}+O\left(x^3\right)\right)=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{x}{3}+O\left(x^2\right)$$ which not only shows the limit but also how it is approached.